# Should BLK and GRN of Pro Mini be connected to upload sketch?

Tags: arduino-pro-mini, uploading, ftdi

Is the following connector is valid for Arduino Pro Mini (no `BLK` and `GRN`)?

[image]

I was told to make a certain Arduino application, and got some Arduino Pro Mini  (ATmeag328 3.3V 8 MHz) with the connector above.

Everytime I tried to upload an example sketch 'Blink', the IDE complains (verbose enabled):

```
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 1 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x83
...
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 10 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x83
```

`resp` may differ (I saw `0x1f` and `0x83`)

But, according to [the official document](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Guide/ArduinoProMini),  I think that I should use some *FTDI* thing, which has 6 pins including BLK and GRN.

I wonder whether I can use the existing 4-pin connector, or whether I must use 6-pin FTDI connector.

Comment: BLK and GRN sound like Wire colors and those may vary from product to product.  Look at what the function of the wires are and not the colors.

Comment: You need a DTR signal to connect to reset to enter the bootloader, of manually enter the bootloader at the right time by pressing the reset button.

Comment: Thank you for comments. I realized that BLK and GRN are not relevant in my case. After compiling, I press reset button manually, start upload, release the button, and upload succeeds. It's somewhat inconvenient. I need to get some board to do it automatically.

Comment: >"After compiling, I press reset button manually" <-- That's due to missing DTR connection.   If your USB TTY adapter does not expose a jumper for DTR, you may be able to solder one on by tracing where the DTR pin is on your particular USB-TTY chip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

If you look at the picture in your link, you would see that `BLK` is ground (`GND`) and `GRN` is `DTR`, that is used to reset the board and enter the bootloader for programming.

As Majenko said, without `DTR` you will need to press the reset button at the right time, to enter the bootloader.